# Confusion surrounding @import behaviour in LESS, using Codekit

Tags: css, compiler-errors, twitter-bootstrap, less

Currently using Bootstrap, compiling with Codekit, and also have a separate style.less that I'm working on.

In variables.less:

```
@blue: #0096EF;
```

In style.less, I have the following:

```
.title-text {color: @blue;}
@import: "variables.less";
```

In bootstrap.less:

```
@import: "style.less";
@import: "variables.less";
```

Am I doing this right? To my mind, when bootstrap is compiled it results in variables.less occurring twice.

Comment: you should be able to go with import of variables.less once in bootstrap as first import instance. Because other wise you tell less to compile bootstrap with all dependencies plus all dependencies with it's dependancies, and as far as i know its not very redundancy proof process.

Comment: in short what i meant, with this set up you tell less to include variables.less twice, at two different points of compiling.

Comment: Ok! I follow that so far (thank you for the added clarification). Following on from this, I want to reference `@blue` in style.less. What's the most efficient way to go about this, seeing as `@blue` has been declared in variables.less?

Comment: here is the question though, are you following twitter bootstraps / boiler plate current schema of import? create a jsfiddle if need to, to communicate this.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by their current schema of import. Do you mean that I should import style.less to bootstrap.less?

Comment: any how i will answer your question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered this is also a Codekit issue too, as I am using Codekit to compile the less files.

Solution:

1. Create style.less and edit it as intended, reference @blue variable
   (not declared in current document)
2. On save, Codekit returns a compile error, due to un-declared variable in style.less. Ignore the error.
3. In bootstrap.less `@import` style.less
4. Save bootstrap.less, it compiles without issue
5. Call bootstrap.css in the html doc

Incidentally, I encountered a Codekit bug between step 2 and 3. After step 2, Codekit no longer watches or compiles anything. To solve, I needed to remove the watched project and then re-add it to Codekit.

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to go with import of variables.less once in bootstrap as first import instance, and do not include it second time in actual style.less. Because you are right on your assumption, it will import variable.less again. meaning you are importing same variables in two locations.

P.S. as long as variables.less that defines variables that you will be using is imported before you access variables themselves you will be fine.

```
@color-black: #000;

.color {
      color: @color-black;
}
```

Comment: Ok. Assuming I only import variables.less to bootstrap. How do I reference a variable declared in variables.less within styles.less?

Comment: @OllyF please accept the answer if you found it helpfull. It does not look like any one else will be pitching in. Thanks.

Comment: Hey there, I actually worked it out in a little more detail myself but Stackoverflow wouldn't let me post the answer until 24 hours later (as I have less than 100 rep). I up voted your answer but, if someone encounters the same issue, it doesn't completely solve it. My solution is below. Although now I've posted it, apparently I have to wait 24 hours before I can accept it.

Comment: If this is a specific to the environment, please revise your question and description, so it makes more sense.